# Confused about Inserting Data in a ManyToOne Relationship in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, hibernate-mapping

I have created These two Entities

**Language**:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Language {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String langName;
    private String paradigm;
}
```

**User**:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Language language;
}
```

So we have several programmers and each programmer has a favourite Language. Multiple Programmers can have same favourite language.

I am trying to create a microService which I will send data to(via an endpoint) and get stored in a database.

I am confused as to how should I be sending my data. Should I first populate the **Language** Entity, then start populating the **User** Entity and everytime I add a Users object, I check whether the corresponding language is present in Language Entity or not?

Or should I directly start with the **User** Entity sending all the fields along with his/her language, make a check whether it exists in the **Language** Entity, if it exists fetch its id and assign it to the **User** foreign key, if it does not exist, then insert it along with the **Person** Object?

I am using the JpaRepository interface for CRUD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load language first. If you using UI then you must have some predefined languages so if language is loaded then you can show them in ui.

While sending user you can pass only id and hibernate will check if id exists then map that id without loading whole object from db.

Add constructor with argument id `Language` class.

```java
public Language(long id) {
  this.id = id;
}
```

Sample user JSON.

```json
{
  "name": "Tony",
  "language": 1
}
```

OR will also work

```json
{
  "name": "Tony",
  "language": {
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

When you save `User` entity then it will automatically map Language with id 1.
When you send JSON your controller will receive object. Spring JacksonMapper will convert json to object.

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

   @PostMapping(value = "/users")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@RequestBody @Valid User userVO) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Do we generally start populating the table which does not contain any foreign key since it wouldn't be dependent on any other table?

Comment: Yes. If you start populating table with foreign key then you must allow null in column else it will throw error. Then later you have to update again with foreign key value after populating foreign table.

Comment: Lets say I send

{
   "name": "Tony",
   "language": "C"
}


So then I'll extract the langName from the object, call the function getByName(String name); Now I have the **Language** Entity object, now what should I do? Create a new **User** object, assign name and the obtained **Language** object and then insert? Would that not create a duplicate entry in the **Language** entity?

Comment: If your `Language` object you assigning to `User` object have *id* then it will not insert new. But if *id* not present in `Language` object then it will create new entry. To avoid duplicate I would suggest to use unique constraint on your db.